# assertThat field by field or compare object

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I'm having an argument with my friend and I would like to know your opinion.

In a test do you think that is better to compare field by field or just create a expectedResultObject and compare it.

For instance:

```
Assert.That(obj.Foo).isEqualTo(FOO);
Assert.That(obj.Test).isEqualTo(TEST);
```

vs

```
Foo expected = new Foo(FOO, TEST);
assertThat(obj).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(expected);
```

In this example we only have two fields but we can have allot more.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about the usingRecuriseComparison() ? If you have an equals method, only assertThat(obj).isEqualTo(expected) doesn't work ?

Comment: Hi, did you see my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can have multiple fields, the expected method is better because you'll be adding the other fields inside the constructors' params. Imagine if you have 100 fields, adding them line by line as you suggested in your first example would be a headache, while adding in the params would be a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Between the two possibilities, I prefer the one without the usingRecursiveComparison().

I wanted to add a few thins :

1. An object is not a data toolbox, so it's not a good thing to add getter/setter to test your object's creation. It's better test a behaviour, a method where you can test the return.
2. Generally I'm not fond of writing more than one assertion in a test.

There is a technique which made assertions more lisibles (with AssertJ but I think you can make this kind of thing with Hamcrest).

The initial class :

```
public class Amount {
    private int value;

    public Integer add(int amountToAdd) {
        value += amountToAdd;
        
        return value;
    }
}
```

Create an Asserter :

```
public class IntegerAsserter extends org.assertj.core.api.AbstractAssert<IntegerAsserter, Integer> {
    IntegerAsserter(Integer actual) {
        super(IntegerAsserter.class, actual);
    }

    public IntegerAsserter isBetweenOneOrTwo() {
        Assert.assertTrue(actual < 2);
        Assert.assertTrue(actual > 1);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Create a new Assertions :

```
public class Assertions extends org.fest.assertions.Assertions {
    public static IntegerAsserter assertThat(Integer actual) {
        return new IntegerAsserter(actual);
    }
}
```

And then use it :

```
public void should_be_between_one_or_two {
    Amount amount = new Amount(0);
    
    Integer newAmount = amount.add(1);

    Assertions.assertThat(obj).isBetweenOneOrTwo();
}
```